# check if installed php version support imagick

Tags: php, imagick

I had some php files that use imagick for resizing pictures stored on my server and after I changed server, imagick functions stopped working. In fact, if I try to use the scripts for resizing pictures (that works on old server), no resized image is created, and no error messages are showing.
How can I check if my hosting support imagick?

Comment: Would'nt phpinfo() help out here?

Comment: What are the old and new server specifications?  What is the OS?  What is the version?  What changed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run this code :

```
<?php
if (extension_loaded('imagick')) {
    echo 'Supported';
} else {
    echo 'Not supported';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the imagick extension is installed and loaded.

Here is the documentation for the `phpinfo` function that should give you the info you're looking for :
http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

Simply create a php file containing

```
<?php
phpinfo ();
```

and look at what it produces. Don't forget to delete it after this, because it could give a lot of informations about what's running on your server, which is never a good thing.

If you need it, here is the doc for imagicck : http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Answer (score -1):

```
echo extension_loaded('imagick') ? "Extension loaded." : "Extension Not loaded";
```

or

```
echo class_exists('Imagick') ? "Class Imagick exists." : "Class Imagick Not exists";
```